# SwiftUI: navigate to a view without getting the back button

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hi im trying to navigate to a new view but dont want to use navigation link because i get the back button. I also want to use the flipHorisontal animation. Is it possible to make this work in SwiftUI?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the function `navigationBarBackButtonHidden` documented here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3338623-navigationbarbackbuttonhidden

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas about how to do the transition animation?

Comment: [This example](https://gist.github.com/fitomad/38d22be227ac9536a10e0d2851c134f5) does what you need w/o NavigationView

Comment: @Asperi Any ideas for this?(look at my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking more about how can i do this:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but using SwiftUI.

Comment: I see the same public SwiftUI module interface as you. There is no way for now (Xcode 11.2, Catalina) to do this in 'pure' SwiftUI, but you can do what you've described in your UIKit controller and then wrap it in UIViewControllerRepresentable to integrate somewhere in SwiftUI workflow.